# Safely auto-encrypt mySQL column using a trigger with a key string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to safely, automatically encrypt a mySQL column using a trigger?

For example, I want to create a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER crypt_trg BEFORE UPDATE ON aaa FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET new.testcol := AES_ENCRYPT(new.testcol, @key);
END;
```

It's obviously not safe to store the encryption key in the database itself, so my plan is to create a variable called `@key` when opening the connection using PHP and then use this in the trigger. Is there any way to give the trigger access to a session variable like that?

Is there any other way to get the key variable from the server filesystem rather than the database?

Are there any other alternatives to getting mySQL to automatically encrypt a column without rewriting every insert/update statement in my application?

Comment: Since triggers are ultimately the database acting independently of client commands, it would not be guaranteed under all circumstances that that variable would be set by a client and hence is at the very least unreliable, at worst impossible.

Comment: If the database can get the key from the filesystem autonomously, then what's the difference to it getting it from "the database itself"?

Comment: Its just slightly more secure. It's obfuscated slightly, and in the event that the db is compromised but the filesystem is not, there's no way to decrypt. I'm open to other suggestions!

Comment: Then why not use the built-in at-rest encryption of InnoDB? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-tablespace-encryption.html

Comment: Damn looks great but minimum version for keyring plugin is mysql 5.7.11 and I'm using 5.5